# Add custom loss function in Torch

Tags: lua, machine-learning, torch, loss

What are the necessary steps to implement a custom loss function in Torch?

It seems like you have to write an implementation for updateOutput and updateGradInput.

Is that all? So then you basically create a new class:

```
local CustomCriterion, parent =   torch.class('CustomCriterion','nn.Criterion')
```

and implement the following two functions:

```
function CustomCriterion:updateOutput(input, target)
function CustomCriterion:updateGradInput(input, target)
```

Is that correct, or is there more to be done?

Also, for the provided criterions these functions are implemented in C, but I suppose a Lua implementation will also work, albeit possibly a little slower?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented functions of the form (in pseudo-code)

```
--assuming input is partitioned in input_a,input_b
--         target is accordingly partitionend in target_a, target_b  
f(input)=MSE(input_a,target_a)+ custom_sutff(input_b,target_b)
```

quite a few times just the way you describe it. So, as far as I know, I think the answer to both your questions is yes.

Basically [nn/MSECriterion.lua](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/MSECriterion.lua) and [this](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/lib/THNN/generic/MSECriterion.c) seem to back this up.